# Change the directory that require() uses in node

Tags: node.js, dependencies, require

I have a system where a "plugin" module required by a main module needs to, itself, require a module, but it needs to require it relative to the directory of the main module. Specifically, I have a package, `pavios`, that requires a module called `pavios-eslint`. `pavios-eslint` needs to require the `babel-eslint` module present in the `node_modules` directory of the `pavios` module, but it instead requires everything from the `node_modules` directory of the `pavios-eslint` module. `process.chdir()` has no effect on it (that is the [intended behavior](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1822)) and I don't know how else to do it without resorting to workarounds or hacks. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I do not have control over the code that requires `babel-eslint`, so I unfortunately cannot change how that code requires it.

Comment: You could install `babel-eslint` in the `pavios-eslint` module as well.

Comment: If you know where the other module is, then just build your own path to the other location and give that to `require()`.  If you don't know where the other module is, then you either need to get its location so you can build a path to it or you need to install the module globally so it can be found from anywhere.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would love to do that, but I can't. See my edit, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just doing things wrong and that's why you're running into these troubles.  Your plug-in should list as dependencies any modules that it does a `require()` on.  Then, when your module is installed NPM will take care of installing, sharing and/or locating those modules for you in the current configuration. That's how dependencies work and that's how you avoid the issue you're in now.  Set up your dependencies properly for each module and this should all be taken care of for you.  Any module that you have listed as a dependency can be loaded from your module with a `require("./modulename")`.  The combination of `require()` and `NPM` will do that for you automatically.

Remember, it's perfectly OK for multiple modules to depend upon the same module.  NPM will handle the updates and location for you and share the common module whenever possible.

If you have module dependencies that are circular and are being loaded at initialization time where A does a require on B and B does a require on A, then you have a different problem to solve.  I can't tell if that is involved here or not.

If this isn't sufficient help, then please spend more time explaining the exact `require()` tree in your code because what you've written above doesn't let me completely understand what you're trying to achieve and why you don't just locate things where they would naturally be found by the `require()` sub-system.  It also isn't clear to use exactly which code in the loading sequence you control or how much of the file system location you can control.

Another possibility here is that rather than having module A load module B which then tries to load module C from module A's location, you could have module module A first load module C and then when it loads module B, it could pass the module handle of C to the module B constructor.  This is one way that a parent module can share one of its modules with a child.